# Is it Possible to develop an App to lock a users exchange calendar?

Tags: exchange-server

I want to be able to install an app on our companies android phones, that locks them from changing appointments in their exchange calendar, because we use it for scheduling them and there appointments,

could that be made?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely. However, there is an easier way! You can accomplish this quickly by modifying their permissions to the Exchange calendar. For example, you give contribute (or better) rights to the people who do the scheduling, but give the users just the read-only rights to their own calendars. Thus, you make the change in one place and it is automagically enforced everywhere.

Comment: I dont think that works, when it is their own personal calendar in their mailbox folder. unfortunately

Comment: Sure does work. Just because they have full rights to their own mailboxes by default does not mean you can't change the rights. I have had to do a lot of tweaks like this, and it works quite well.

Comment: Have you tested in exchange 2010? That is what i am currently running, and I can take their permissions away and they still are able to change their own calendars

Comment: I have done it on Exchange 2007 and 2003, but not yet on 2010. You might need to add explicit "Deny" permissions to override their default full-control.